# Java: why is my output different every time I go to run in the terminal

Tags: java

Java: Logic error, not wanting i want in multiple classes, need help it is killing me
Hi, I am new to the community and I desperately need help, I am pulling my hair out.
I have Java 6 using Blue J and it is just not working for me for what I want.

There are 2 classes and they won't speak efficiently to each other.
Take a look, (yes you don't have to give me suggestions because this is homework but i just can't figure this out and my teacher ran out of time and i have a exam tomorrow.)

I am going mad look at **driver** class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TeacherDriver
{

public static void main ( String args[])
{

System.out.println( "My favorite Teachers are in rooms: 225, 123, 237" +
                    "\nEnter a room number to learn more about the teacher (or -1 to Stop): "        );

int rmnum2 = 0,rmnum = 0;
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

for ( int counter = 100; counter >= 1; counter--)
{
    rmnum = input2.nextInt();
    if (rmnum == -1)break;
    teacher teacherObject = new teacher(rmnum);
    System.out.println(teacherObject.toString());
}//end of the for loop to keep going through the same processes
System.out.println( "Thanks for playing" );
}//end of the main method of teacher to run program
}//end of class for the program complete, Teacher Class
}
```

And here is the **Teacher** class,

```
public class teacher
{
String name, catchphrase,teacher;
int roomnumber, rmnum, rmnum2, input2;

public teacher(int rmnum)
{
if (rmnum == 225){
    name = "Mr. Clark";
    catchphrase = "Just do it.";
    roomnumber = 225;
}
if (rmnum == 123){
    name = "Mr. Harris";
    catchphrase = "Do the essays and you will pass.";
    roomnumber = 123;
}
if (rmnum == 237){
    name = "Mr. Turley";
    catchphrase = "Give a perfect effort.";
    roomnumber = 237;
}
System.out.println ( "I don't have a teacher in that room." );
System.out.println("Always show");
}//end of method to input items
public String toString()
{
String str = "You chose: " + name + 
"\nRoom Number: " + roomnumber +
"\nCatch Phrase is " + catchphrase ;
return str;
}//string of argument that the string is recalled for putting all the items together.
}//end of teacher class for teachers info
```

What I **want** is this output of

```
My favorite Teachers are in rooms: 220, 130, 201
Enter a room number to learn more about the teacher (or ­‐1 to stop):
130 
You chose: Ms. English
They're in room: 130
Their cathcphrase is "This above all; to thine own self be true."
Type another( -1 to stop)
201

You chose: Sra. Spanish
They're in room: 201
Their catch phrase is "Via con tacos"
type another ( -1 to stop)
111
I don't have a favorite teacher in that room!

Type another( -1 to stop)
-1
Thanks for playing>
```

This is pretty stupid item that I need help on and its right in front of me probably.  I want the (I don't have a teacher) not appear and Here is what I keep getting.

```
My favorite Teachers are in rooms: 225, 123, 237
Enter a room number to learn more about the teacher (or -1 to Stop):
123
I don't have a teacher in that room.
Always show
You chose: Mr. Harris
Room Number: 123
Catch Phrase is Do the essays and you will pass.
237
I don't have a teacher in that room.
Always show
You chose: Mr. Turley
Room Number: 237
Catch Phrase is Give a perfect effort.
225
I don't have a teacher in that room.
Always show
You chose: Mr. Clark
Room Number: 225
Catch Phrase is Just do it.
-1
Thanks for playing
```

What in the heck am I doing wrong, yes i could make this more efficient with a switch but i just used what i know, so Is there anything you guys can help me with. This would mean a lot. **I need help on why this output is so different then the one I want.**
Thanks
P.s. I need to have 2 classes!, and
**the 2 outputs don't have to be the same teacher.**

Comment: Hint: Learn how conditions work and then look at the teacher constructor code.

Comment: @jdog1218 why donot you use switch case ?

Comment: My teacher didn't teach us anything about it and its kind of a late project now. I will definitely use it next time. This is too much hard ach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a way to to tell your code to not execute the last 2 statements if `rnum` is not `225,123,237` What you can do is this:

```
public teacher(int rmnum){
    if (rmnum == 225){
        name = "Mr. Clark";
        catchphrase = "Just do it.";
        roomnumber = 225;
    }else if (rmnum == 123){
        name = "Mr. Harris";
        catchphrase = "Do the essays and you will pass.";
        roomnumber = 123;
    }else if (rmnum == 237){
        name = "Mr. Turley";
        catchphrase = "Give a perfect effort.";
        roomnumber = 237;
    }else
        System.out.println ( "I don't have a teacher in that room." );
        System.out.println("Always show");
}
```

or @Scary Wombat 's answer will do as well.

Comment: i keep forgetting the else-if statment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try changing your code so that it returns after setting the correct data

e.g.

```
if (rmnum == 225){
    name = "Mr. Clark";
    catchphrase = "Just do it.";
    roomnumber = 225;
    return;
}
if (rmnum == 123){
    name = "Mr. Harris";
    catchphrase = "Do the essays and you will pass.";
    roomnumber = 123;
    return;
}
if (rmnum == 237){
    name = "Mr. Turley";
    catchphrase = "Give a perfect effort.";
    roomnumber = 237;
    return;
}
```

Of course it would be cleaner as less repetitive if you had a constructor that took `name` `catchphrase` and `roomnumber`

Comment: that is in the constructor class which automatically has a void return.

Comment: Yes, but as you are not calling it, it is continuing on to `System.out.println ( "I don't have a teacher in that room." );`

Comment: @jdog1218 calling `return` in a void method does not mean that the method must or will or have to return something. It means that you execute no further than that `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks so much you solved 1 of 2 problems, now when you input a wrong number in the class I keep getting a null in the terminal.

Comment: kind of thing,  You chose: null
Room Number: 0
Catch Phrase is null

Comment: That is because you are still calling `System.out.println(teacherObject.toString());` but the variables are still null.  Either test for null or set to ""

Comment: Thanks xgeorgekx will know for next time.